# It seems that I cannot parse_dates on two or more colunms

Tags: python, pandas, types, multiple-columns, data-analysis

I parse_dates when I pd.read_excel, but it only works on one columns "ClassStartDate", but fails on the other "ClassEndDate".

```
PSL1= pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\xx.xlsx",parse_dates=["ClassStartDate","ClassEndDate"])
PSL1[["ClassStartDate","ClassEndDate"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you use dicts. Please check if you did not make a typo in Excel. Please check if the names are really exactly `ClassStartDate` and `ClassEndDate`.

Comment: I check again and confirm no typo in excel. I can print both columns, but only "ClassStartDate" has been transformed into dtype: datetime64[ns], the other columns still type (str).

Comment: Without seeing the Excel sheet it is difficult to answer the question

Comment: I suppose if I can print the column out using the name "ClassEndDate", it would the correct spelling in the excel.